# Lower internet speed through router than internet speed from ISP

Tags: networking, router, internet

I have an internet connection of 500Mbps/100Mbps (tested through my PC using ethernet). For a project I'm working on, I decided to create a small LAN network using an old router which supports 5GHz 802.11n connection. I only have one ethernet wall port in my room though, so I removed it from my PC and connected it to the router instead. Then, I connected my PC to the router using another ethernet cable. When I tried running a speed test, the highest I could get was 93Mpbs/94Mbps. I also tested this through my phone using WIFI and got a lower result, so the issue isn't with the 2nd ethernet cable I'm using.

The router's bandwidth is also higher, I used iperf3 to check how fast the LAN connection over WIFI is and it was between 150-250Mbps.

How come only the internet speed is slow when the router is capable of much higher speeds?

Comment: Sounds like your router has low internal throughput. Check your router specifications for that.  Router port speeds have nothing to do with internal throughput. Also upgrade the firmware on the router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the specs on your router.
This is perfectly consistent if the WAN/LAN ports of the router are limited to 100 Mbps. Which isn't unusual for a router that is a couple of years old.

Comment: Thanks I went through the router's info on its settings page and it mentions that the WAN port has 100 Mbps speed.

Comment: Port speeds are *never exceed* speeds. Additionally, consumer routers (often) have (much) lower effective forwarding rates than their port speeds.